# prometheus_client ImportError: cannot import name 'Info'

Tags: python-3.x, prometheus

When I have this line in my file

```
from prometheus_client import CollectorRegistry, pushadd_to_gateway, Info
```

Code runs just fine when I use 2.7 python interpreter.

However in 3.6 it gives:
     ImportError: cannot import name 'Info'

```
from prometheus_client import CollectorRegistry, pushadd_to_gateway, Info

def write_to_gateway(key, value):
    registry = CollectorRegistry()

    i = Info('sql_monitor_results', 'These are results of SQL queries converted into key/value info', registry=registry)
    i.info({key: value})
    pushadd_to_gateway('localhost:9091', job='MonitorResults', registry=registry)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_to_gateway("xxx", "yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you've an older version of the library installed for Python 3, upgrade it with `pip3`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It turned out I did not run pip install in virtualenv. So it acually worked from prompt but not from PyCharm. After source bin/activate and pip3 install prometheus_client it worked.

Thanks again,
--vadim